# How can Dash to Panel be installed on Ubuntu 22.04.3?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, ubuntu-dock, gnome-panel

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/

- I've installed gnome extensions or shell.
- I've downloaded the Dash to Panel zip file. This file is downloaded dash-to-paneljderose9.github.com.v59.shell-extension.zip
- I've rebooted Ubuntu
- there's no option to move the Top Bar thingy into the Dock down the bottom...it wastes previous space and blocks dragging windows along monitors.
- The documentation doesn't help, just says how to use CLI to install gnome shell or extensions.
- Can't find a clear video guide on it, the install just works on videos but not on my Ubuntu.
- Chromium browser has GNOME Shell installed.
- Ubuntu Dock has been moved by Ubuntu's Settings to the bottom and autohide
- It's this superfluent Dash Panel thingy at the top of Ubuntu, taking up valuable monitor space and bumps windows when I drag them from monitor 1-3 and vice versa.  The top panel thingy needs to be merged into the Dock at the bottom.
- The Dash-to-panel website says I've install GNOME Shell integration is running.
- I ran: sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
  sudo apt-get install gnome-browser-connector
- Chrome extensions says: GNOME Shell extensions website Has access to this site
- I'm researching what Extension Manager is https://itsfoss.com/extension-manager/, however this seems to not solve the issue and rather than this work-around, I'm sure there's a clearer path with fewer steps to install and run.

Answer (score 0):

Go in extension manager.

Click on browse.

Write « dash to panel ».

Click at the right of the search bar.

Choose third line instead of « popularity » to be able to find « dash to panel ».